# How can I export a Materialise Magics Project as a STL file?

Tags: 3d-models, file-formats, materialise-magics

I created a new project in Materialise Magics, added a few parts (different STLs), moved them around in certain positions and now I want to export this project into another STL, containing my recent work.

The export menu seems to be all grey, like this function is not available. Do I have to do some repairing first or something similar? Or Magics needs other software in order to export a Magics Project to a STL file?

Comment: It's pretty common for software to prevent export of a failed model. From the little I've researched via YouTube videos, there is a wizard to help you find the failure points, some automatic repair and then perhaps manual repair required. I expect you'll find the export option returns when completed.

Comment: consider to also check each STL for validity (manifold) or need for repair.

Comment: I just finished doing that. I think the Support Generation module is not working or missing at all. I may need to find another software that supports adding multiple STL files in the same workspace, lets me do rotation and translation movements, edit coordinates and combine them in a single mesh to export the final model into a single STL instead of multiple. Do you know such of software? I have a student account at Autodesk and I'm now currently download Inventor.

Comment: I'm a big fan of blender and meshmixer, both free, but I can't say with certainty if either will do as you require. They are both more "organic" modeling programs while Inventor or SolidWorks and it's ilk are parametric and engineering oriented.

Comment: I found a workaround eventually. I moved each STL in the designated coordinates, exported them separately from Magic's "Save Part As" option and just imported them in 123D Design, because it keeps the original coordinates, and exported the design after in a single STL. Anyway, thanks :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I gather from your post that you are trying to export a build file containing multiple individual pieces, possibly to be printed. I suggest using the 'Merge' tool to join each of the individual STL's into one file. You can then save it as as single part or export it to a printer. This information comes from my experience as an Additive manufacturing technician. The following link is a Github repo containing a workflow on this process:

[Magic's Build File Creation](https://github.com/rp-mcguire/Magics-Build-File)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `save project as` or `export` click `save part as`, this defaults to an STL file.